# Using variables in bash script command parameters

Tags: bash, variables, command

I've been trying to start a number of terminals based on a variable `i` and execute a command in each of them:

```
#!/bin/bash
read number
for ((i=1;i<=number;i++))
do
xterm -e 'cockroach start --insecure --store="node${i}"'
done
```

However it doesn't seems to replace `${i}` for me in the parameter of the command. I've tried using `--store=node${i}`, `--store=node$i` or `--store="node" + ${i}` none seem to work.

Anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: Swap your quotes: `xterm -e "cockroach start --insecure --store='node$i'"`. `$i` needs to be expanded when `xterm` runs, not when `cockroach` runs.

Comment: oh... yeah I see, thanks alot